# Anyone know the default password on a Lexmark 4600 MFP?

Tags: passwords, lexmark-printer

Just opened the package, greeted with an admin screen. The password isn't blank and there's nothing I can see in the user manual.  Google searches seem to turn up nothing, also.

Comment: grr... as you'd guess, it was set to "password". /epic fail, sorry to waste anyone's time.

Comment: Epic fail for the user manual if it does not clearly list the password. (And a regular fail if the manual showed an example with the literal text password. That would be unclear and should not get past the proof readers).

Answer (score 3):

The default password is, drumroll............

"password"!!

/slap

Comment: http://instantrimshot.com/